# How to get notified about which contact is deleted or updated from device Phonebook in Android

Tags: android, android-contacts, contentobserver

Using the **ContentObserver** i get to know that there has been some change in the contacts database but I need to know which contact has been deleted or updated from device contact list. Is there any working example which can achieve the same? Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Out of the entire contacts I have in the Phonebook, there is only one particular contact for which I need to know if the content has changed. In such case, can I have an observer just for one specific contact and not for the entire phonebook ?

Comment: Assuming you manage to query the provider before the sync adapter associated with it manages to process the update you can check the `DIRTY` or `DELETED` flags in `RawContacts`. The other option is to mirror `VERSION` and `ID` and match the contents of the provider against your local copy, which is when it starts to get messy. (Btw,   one call to the `ContentObserver` may indicate that several contacts have been changed or deleted)